# Optimized way to create a text menu without creating new objects

Tags: java, user-interface, optimization, menu

I have a small program with a text based user menu. A switch case is doing the input validation for me, because the user only enters integers which I validate.

The menu looks like this:

```
----------------------
(1) Manage articles
(2) Manage customers
(3) Close
----------------------
Please enter your number:
```

This menu is created through an extra method.
When I enter `1`, I call another method which contains another do-while loop, this time validating the article menu and so on. The second menu looks like this:

```
Manage articles
----------------------
(1) Show
(2) Add
(3) Change
(4) Delete
(5) Back
----------------------
Please enter your number:
```

But to switch back to the previous menu, I always create a new instance of my class and call the first method to show the first menu.

The result is: when I switch many times between the menus, I always create a new instance of my program.

I think there are better ways to do such a multiple-layer-reading and like to know how to perform better here.

**Update:**

```
package articlemanagement.menu;

import articlemanagement.model.Artikel;

import articlemanagement.verwaltung.ArticleManagement;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserInterface {

    private ArticleManagement articleManagement;

    private UserInterface() {
        this.articleManagement = new ArticleManagement();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserInterface userInterface = new UserInterface();

        userInterface.showDefaultInterface(userInterface);

        System.out.println("See you next time!");
    }

    private void showDefaultInterface(UserInterface userInterface) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Welcome");
            System.out.println("----------------------");
            System.out.println("(1) Articles");
            System.out.println("(2) Customers");
            System.out.println("(3) Shop");
            System.out.println("(4) End");
            System.out.println("----------------------");
            System.out.print("Please enter a number:");

            input = scanner.nextInt();

            switch (input) {
                case 1:
                    userInterface.showArtikelInterface(userInterface);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("todo");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("todo");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Bye");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        } while (input != 4);

        System.exit(1);
    }

    /**
     * Show overview
     */
    private void showArtikelInterface(UserInterface userInterface) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Manage your articles");
            System.out.println("----------------------");
            System.out.println("(1) Show");
            System.out.println("(2) Add");
            System.out.println("(3) Modify");
            System.out.println("(4) Delete");
            System.out.println("(5) Go Back");
            System.out.println("----------------------");
            System.out.print("Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl für Ihr Menü ein:");

            int input = scanner.nextInt();

            switch (input) {
                case 1: // show
                    zeigeArtikel();
                    break;
                case 2: // add
                    System.out.println("todo");
                    break;
                case 3: // modify
                    System.out.println("todo");
                    break;
                case 4: // delete
                    System.out.println("todo");
                    break;
                case 5: // back
                    System.out.println("Going back...");
                    // bad style?
                    userInterface.showDefaultInterface(userInterface);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        } while (scanner.nextInt() != 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the method `static`.

Comment: Already thought about that but wouldn't that be bad style?

Comment: Not necessarily. You're not showing your code so we can't know.

Comment: I added a gist, maybe it's more clear now.

Comment: Post code in the question, not as external sources.

Comment: Did that now, thought it would be too much code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But to switch back to the previous menu, I always create a new instance of my class and call the first method to show the first menu.

You're not creating a new instance every time. You created exactly one instance in `main` and that's it. With that being said, there are some odd design choices that you made.

#### Design

You have a `UserInterface` class which has the ability to print some text depending on the context. Two general designs would be:

1. Static approach (utility/handler/manager...)

   ```
   public class UserInterface {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           UserInterface.showDefaultInterface();
       }

       private static void showDefaultInterface() {

           // ...
           showArtikelInterface();
           // ...
       }

       private static void showArtikelInterface() {

           // ...
           showDefaultInterface();
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```

   or you can create a type to represent the context if you need more flexibility (doesn't seem so):

   ```
   interface Context {

       void show();
   }
   ```

   and

   ```
   class UserInterface {

       static void showContext(Context context) { context.show(); }
   }
   ```
2. Instance approach

   ```
   public class UserInterface {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           UserInterface userInterface = new UserInterface();
           userInterface.showDefaultInterface();
       }

       private void showDefaultInterface() {

           // ...
           showArtikelInterface();
           // ...
       }

       private void showArtikelInterface() {

           // ...
           showDefaultInterface();
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```

But you have a mix which doesn't make sense in which you pass the instance to itself:

```
UserInterface userInterface = new UserInterface();
userInterface.showDefaultInterface(userInterface);
```

and same with the `showArtikelInterface` method. An instance has access to itself, so no reason to do this in your case (a case where an instance method would take instances of its type can be in data structures where you have chains/links/nodes...).

#### Loop condition

Another odd thing is your `while` conditions

```
while (scanner.nextInt() != 5); // and the other one
```

where it should be `> 5` and `< 1`. Though I guess this is just your current test code.

#### Shared resources

Last thing is that you can share the `Scanner` object between methods instead of creating one each time. Promote it to a field (`static` or not depending on your design choice).

Comment: Thank you very much! I always thought I should avoid static due to the sentence "Static is evil.".

Comment: @Zumarta I tend to avoid catchphrases when it comes to objective areas :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean? :)

Comment: @Zumarta "Static is evil." is a catch phrase, avoid those.